# how to get a text from a window

Tags: delphi, window

This is the window of the application used to view TV Channels on my BT878 TVTunner.

[image]

The number 6 from the middle is the number of the channel.
I know the handle of the window.
Is there any way (preferably in Delphi programming language) to get that number...?

Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

If it used an interface of normal Windows controls then you could enumerate the child windows and find the one which contained that text.

However, this looks like a custom drawn window and so I suspect that you only chance would be to do a screen scrape to a bitmap and process that.

You could use Spy to inspect the app and see whether or not there are child windows.

Comment: @David Thank you. There are child windows: 3 TPanel's. The number is not on them. I know that I can take a snapshot and get the number from it but is a very slow method + a lot of coding = probably not worth it...

Comment: @John If there are no children of the panels then I think you're only option will be a screen scrape

Comment: You could capture images of the digits 0-9 used by the channel area, then add those images to your app's resources and simple do pixel-by-pixel comparisons at runtime.  Just looking at the UI, its pretty easy to determine the image coordinates you would have to look at.  It is a small area, and would not take very many comparisons.  The coding is likely to not be as difficult as you think, and image comparisons can be quite fast if you look at the image scanlines directly.

Comment: @David , @Remy Ok then. Can you show me some code sample on how to do that ...?

Comment: @John No, Sorry. Why don't you do it yourself. You need to search for articles on screen capture and it should be easy from there.

Comment: @David I (somehow) understand why you're saying that. Maybe because you want that I learn something, maybe because you don't want me to be lazy... Yes, you're partially correct. But: 1. I don't ask for the hole program but just a simple example; 2. I'm not a kid but a 36 years old who doesn't have so much time available (I have to work too). But it's your choice... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @john i don't have spare time either nothing more to it than that

Answer (score 0):

If that channel field has its own `HWND`, then try sending it a `WM_GETTEXT` message (use Spy++, Winspector, or other similar tool to see the parent/child relationships of the window's `HWND`s).  If that does not work, then you may have to resort to capturing an image of the app's window, extracting the pixels used for the channel number, and then parse them to determine which number is being displayed.

Comment: thank you. It doesn't appear to have it's own hwnd, at least that's what I see with Spy++. So I can't send a message. Regarding the capture, it's like I said to David: is a very slow method + a lot of coding = probably not worth it...